# What are journals of pure mathematics with low impact factor

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Please provide list of mathematics journal which accept pure mathematical research snd have a low impact factor as our research is not very big breakthrough.

Comment: If you feel that your "research is not very big breakthrough," then consider submitting it to a local journal, perhaps one in your university or one made by a local mathematics society.  Never, ever submit to a predatory journal.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

Consider sending your paper to a journal that publishes work like yours (depth and area). Don't bother with impact factor.

Comment: Given the number of questions here in which someone wants to get into a highly ranked program, have a highly ranked advisor, publish in a highly ranked journal, choose a subfield that is considered "highly ranked", etc., it crossed my mind that this might have been a troll question. However, this is not 1990s Usenet and the writing style seems too real (most people who try to fake ESL writing go way overboard), so I think it's probably legitimate.